# Wrong working directory after opening file

Tags: working-directory

I currently have the problem that when I open a file, I always have a certain working directory. This is a problem, because Vim doesn't find tags files anymore. I have not set anything like this in .vimrc. Any ideas where this problem could come from? Does Vim save the working directory for certain files? How can I turn that off?

I can change the directory with :cd of course, but I would like Vim to just stay in the directory where I launched it like the project root or the root of the Git repository.

Comment: Did you install any plugins recently? Does `:verbose pwd` say "window" or "global"?

Comment: The last plugin I installed was fzf, but that was a week ago. ``:verbose pwd`` says global.

Comment: Can you share more details? Please [edit] the question to say more. What's the correct directory you expect Vim to be in and what is the wrong one it ends up in? How are those related to the directory where you start Vim or the directory of the file you edit? Is the behavior always consistent (always same wrong directory)? Does it also happen under `vim --clean`, which will skip loading plug-ins and your vimrc settings?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I realized this for some files in the project I am currentyl working in. Now that I've discovered :cd to change the directory manually, I did not encounter this issue anymore. For files outside this project it seems fine. What I can say is that it wasn't always the same directory. Seemed like it saved the directory for certain files. What is the difference between the "global" and "window" mode?

Comment: I was just grasping at straws. If it had said "window" then it would have suggested that some plugin was changing it and/or that it was being changed based on filetype.